# Is it true that any continuous function $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ can be approximated by polynomials?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I think it's true, but how to prove it? By weierstrass approximation theorem we can approximate uniformly any continuous function on a closed interval $[a,b]$ by a sequence of polynomial function i.e., given any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ $\implies$ $|p_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ $,\forall x\in [a,b].$ I am asking whether it is possible to approximate a continuous function $f$ by a sequence of polynomial functions on $[0,\infty).$

Thanks!

Comment: In what sense? The supremum norm?

Comment: Related: (for closed intervals) [Weierstrass Approximation Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassApproximationTheorem.html).

Comment: That won't work because $[0,\infty)$ isn't compact.

Comment: @Workaholic Yes.

Comment: I saw an answer somewhere. Not true since polynomial goes to infinity at infinity, you can not approximate a function that is bounded.

Comment: This question is ambiguous, you need to define what you mean by 'approximated by'.

Comment: @copper.hat Isn't it clear from context? He cites the Weierstrass theorem, in which "approximated by" is understood as $p_n\to f$ uniformly.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: If it was clear to me I would not ask. The Weierstrass theorem text was added 13 mins. ago, my comment many hours before that.

Comment: $[0,\infty)$ is not compact, so Weierstrass approximation theorem does not apply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not true. Polynomials of degree $\ge1$ are unbounded on $[0,\infty)$. This implies that a bounded function cannot be approximated uniformly by polynomials on $[0,\infty)$.

### Edit

This is added after reading Henning Makholm's comment.

> If $\{p_n\}$ is a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to a
>   function $f$ on $[0,\infty)$, then $f$ is a polynomial.

**Proof**. By Cauchy's uniform convergence criterion, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$
n\ge N\implies|p_N(x)-p_n(x)|\le1\quad\forall x\in[0,\infty).
$$
$p_N-p_n$ is a bounded polynomialon $[0,\infty)$, thus it is a constant $c_n$:
$$
p_n=p_N+c_n\quad n\ge N.
$$
Since $\{p_n(x)\}$ converges for all $x\ge0$, $c_n$ also converges. Let $c$ be its limit. Then $f=p_N+c$.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for approximation of bounded functions

Comment: @AhmedHussein If it does not work for bounded functions, it does not work for continuous bounded functions.

Comment: I agree. But the OP doesn't require their function to be bounded, they are asking about approximation of continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: @AhmedHussein But some continuous functions are bounded, and no polynomial can uniformly bound those ones. Therefore we can't find a way to take an arbitrary continuous function and uniformly bound it by a polynomial, because the procedure would fail if we presented it with a bounded example.

Comment: @AhmedHussein I have shown that there are continuous functions that cannot be uniformly approximated by polynomials on $[0,\infty)$: the bounded continuous functions. They are not the only ones; $e^{x^k}$ , $k>0$,  for instance. But there are functions that can be so aproximated: polynomials.

Comment: Of course. I was not paying close attention. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It's even worse: A sequence of polynomials converges uniformly if and only if it is eventually constant, so the polynomials themselves are the _only_ functions that can be approximated uniformly by polynomials..